# CafePress Widget Not Showing Products

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to put a CafePress Widget on a website, using the tool provided here: http://www.cafepress.com/cp/widgets/ but it's not working. The box gets added, but no products within.

There's an error in the Console that shows that [cpwidget.js](http://content.cpcache.com/cplabs/cpwidget.js) is trying to access `search.json` with a relative URL. When I put this code in a jsFiddle this is the error I got:
*http://fiddle.jshell.net/search.json?query=&pageNumber=1&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=cpwidget 404 (NOT FOUND)*
(not sure what the snippet error will look like, so providing this too). My website returned the same error.

So this seems to be the problem, **but I'm finding it hard to believe that this widget simply does not work. I couldn't possibly be the only person who's ever tried to use it?**

```js
var CPwaitForLoad,jQwaitForLoad,init=function(){if("CPWidget"in window)window.clearTimeout(CPwaitForLoad),CPWidget.init({title:"My CafePress Products",topcolor:"#8CBE21",bottomcolor:"#79A618",bgcolor:"#FFFFFF",rows:1,cols:1,imgsize:"125",prodtitle:"true",partnerid:"",shopid:"",tags:""});else{CPwaitForLoad=window.setTimeout(init,200);var t=document.createElement("SCRIPT");t.src="http://content.cpcache.com/cplabs/cpwidget.js?v=5",t.type="text/javascript",document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}},jQinit=function(){if("jQuery"in window)window.clearTimeout(jQwaitForLoad),init();else{var t=document.createElement("SCRIPT");t.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js",t.type="text/javascript",document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t),jQwaitForLoad=window.setTimeout(jQinit,200)}};jQinit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cpwidget'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same issue: I believe widgets are no longer supported. If you look at their builder page (http://www.cafepress.com/cp/widgets/) you'll find the links to the Blogger & Joomla no longer work, either, and WordPress version is 2 years out of date with a low score.

Did you get any technical support responses from CafePress? I sent a contact email but have yet to get a response.

My answer: CafePress widgets no longer work.

Comment: I acutally noticed this as well after the fact (the Blogger/Joomla thing). My client wasn't insistent we solve this so I never contacted their support, but kept this question around as it seemed useful- couldn't find anyone else asking about this.